# How does it make sense to represent "cartesian coordinates vectors" as "homogeneous coordinates points at infinity"?

Tags: computer-science, projective-geometry

(I will denote points with coordinates (x,y) as P(x,y), vectors with coordinates (x,y) as V(x,y) and arrays as [a,b,c,d...]).

We want points and vectors to have certain properties, i.e a vector added to a point gives you a new point, a point subtracted from another point gives you the vector between them, adding two vectors give you a new vector.

In computer graphics, points and vectors are usually represented with arrays. There are different ways to implement this, the naive way is to say that P(x,y) = [x,y] and that V(x,y) = [x,y]. However there is a problem here, you can’t really tell points and vectors apart, so the “fix” is to add an extra component which is 0 for vectors and 1 for points. So P(x,y) = [x,y,1] and V(x,y) = [x,y,0].

The nice thing about the “fix” is that it preserves the vector and point properties automatically.

$P(x_1,y_1) + V(x_2,y_2) = [x_1,y_1,1] + [x_2,y_2,0] = [x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,1] = P(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$

$P(x_1,y_1) - P(x_2,y_2) = [x_1,y_1,1] - [x_2,y_2,1] = [x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2,0] = V(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)$

$V(x_1,y_1) + V(x_2,y_2) = [x_1,y_1,0] + [x_2,y_2,0] = [x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,0] = V(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$

The explaination to why this works is that we are actually using "homogeneous coordinates". I am familiar with homogeneous coordinates from projective geometry, but I fail to see the whole analogy.

P(x,y) = [x,y,1] makes sense, but why V(x,y)=[x,y,0]? That would mean that vectors are being represented by points at infinity. The explanation I've for this is that points of infinity are essentially just a direction in the plane. That makes sense to me, but aren't vectors direction AND magnitude? In homogeneous coordinates e.g [1,2,0]=[2,4,0] so we loose the difference between V(1,2) and V(2,4), in other words we lose the magnitude.

Is there something about this representation I am not seeing?

The source of my question is from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX4H_ctggYo&t=618s, relevant part is 10:18 to 13:00

Comment: These coordinates do not work as "homogeneous" coordinates for exactly the reasons you mentioned (mainly the loss of information about magnitude of vectors). In fact the whole thing seems silly to me -- is it really worth the 50% increase in storage requirements?

Comment: Now that you linked to the video, the video reminded me of the mathematical technique of doing an affine transformation (linear transformation plus translation) in two dimensions via a $3\times3$ matrix where the bottom row of the matrix is $0,0,1.$ If a "point" is $(x,y,1)^T$ (column vector) and a "vector" is $(x,y,0)^T$ then multiplication on the left by the matrix applies the translation to the point but not to the vector, and this is the desired result. Whether it literally happens exactly that way *in software* is a different question.

Comment: But even in the video, the connection to the projective plane is still tenuous: points at infinity might be regarded as "directions" in some sense, but vectors have both direction *and magnitude*. In fact the line at infinity has only one dimension whereas the vector space over a plane has two dimensions, so the two sets really are not a good analogy with each other at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that both $[1,2,0]$ and $[2,4,0]$ represent a point at infinity in the direction $[1,2]$. But the vector length is not lost -- the length of the vector $[x,y,0]$ can obviously be computed as $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

From a software point of view, I don't think this unification of points and vectors is worth the extra storage space. I'd suggest that you implement a Point class and a Vector class, plus all the functions you need to operate on Points and Vectors.

Another approach is to just assume some fixed origin, implement a Vector class, and represent a point by its position vector relative to the chosen origin. This will work ok, though it seems pedagogically wrong, to me -- points and vectors are **not** the same thing.

Use of homogeneous coordinates is nice because it removes the need for special casing and error returns: the function that intersects two lines will *always* return a point, even if that point happens to be at infinity. But, again, not worth the storage space, IMO.

Comment: The proposed scheme actually contradicts the last paragraph, because it rejects the concept of points at infinity; the point that would have been returned for the intersection of two lines is said to be a vector, not a point. But that's because the scheme is "homogeneous coordinates" in form only and not in any meaningful way.